# Cannot see the output for the simple "hello world" python code in terminal

Tags: python, macos

I don't understand why I can't see an output on the terminal when I run the following code (Python 2.7):

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import sys

    def main():

      if len(sys.argv) >=2:
        name = sys.argv[1]
      else:
        name = "Heisenberg"
      print "Hello", name

    if "__name__" == "__main__":
      main()
```

Comment: First of all, name is local in both if and else branches if you do not declare/use it before the clause...

Answer (score 5):

`__name__`should be without `"`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

`"__name__"` is a string so it will never be equal to `"__main__"`